# Fastest way to query small selection from a large table?

Tags: mysql, database

I have a music table with >70,000 tracks and want to query a playlist out of that. I am currently running a query that has an ' AND track.id IN ( select id from playlist where pid=5 ) ' statement. Is there a faster way to pull the rows out other than a subselect?

Comment: You could likely just use a "normal" join sequence through the M-M relation table and this is the *first* approach I'd use as it just fits in with the "basic" Relational Algebra model well. With the correct indices setup it should be lickity-split (normally just a hash-join or comparable) for any reasonable amount of data -- at least far more than 70k songs. Relational SQL databases are *designed* for this sort of thing. If in doubt, check out the actual query execution plans (I have no idea what mysql might transform that subselect into) and execution timings. See `EXPLAIN`.

Comment: "small selection from a large table" screams "index". Is it too slow now?

Comment: The table is indexed, is that what you mean?

Comment: There is "indexed" and "adequately-indexed-for-usage-in-a-way-that-the-query-optimizer-can-work-with-without-being-over-indexed" :P Check out the query plans and execution timings. Without all the details including failing functional requirements (if any) there really isn't much to do :) If it works well now, might as well just go with it. I was simply putting forward my experience on the issue in the comment above -- but, once again: the *query plan* will tell generally indicate "how efficient" it is.

Answer (score 1):

I am nothing but an enthusiast, and completely self-taught, so if I am repeating what anyone above already said, please forgive.

However, to me your use of the  Sub-Select seems like extra work for the Db, and less scalable. Seems like there should be a Music table (tblMusic, PK_SongID), a playlists table (tblPlaylist PK_PLaylistID), and a reference table indexing them to eachother (tblPlaylist_tblMusic FK_tblPLaylist.PLaylistID, FK_tblMusic.SongID). This table would essentially be the Many-to-many indexing relationship between playlists and songs. You would then simply do the INNER JOIN between the three tables, and set your SELECT Criteria to PlaylistID.

I am suspecting that this was what pst was describing above, but I could be wrong . . .